# Configure dynamically my palette color with NextJS and Tailwindcss?

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css, dynamically-generated

I want to be able to switch my website theme color from value receive by my API.
I am working with NextJS and Tailwindcss

I want to configure Tailwindcss to be able to use class like "bg-primary-500", "text-primary-400", etc ... whitch "primary" contain the value of my color palette.

Step 1 :

Call the Api to receive the theme value. The result will be a String like "leaf" and define whitch color palette need to be load.

step 2 :

Inject this value to tailwindcss config et configure the the primary color value with the good palette color.

step 3 :

Be able to use class like "text-primary-500" in my code !

I have Tailwindcss already configure and working in my project.

Here is my tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  purge: {
    mode: "layer",
    layers: ["components", "utilities"],
    content: ["./components/**/*.tsx", "./pages/**/*.tsx"],
  },
  important: true,
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      sans: ["Open Sans", "sans-serif"],
      serif: ["Merriweather", "serif"],
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        leaf: {
          100: "#F3F8E8",
          200: "#E2EFC4",
          300: "#D1E5A1",
          400: "#AED15B",
          500: "#8BBD14",
          600: "#7DAA12",
          700: "#53710C",
          800: "#3F5509",
          900: "#2A3906",
        },
        casal: {
          100: "#E9EFF0",
          200: "#C8D7DA",
          300: "#A6BFC3",
          400: "#648F97",
          500: "#215F6A",
          600: "#1E565F",
          700: "#143940",
          800: "#0F2B30",
          900: "#0A1D20",
        },
        coral: {
          100: "#FDF1EC",
          200: "#FBDBCF",
          300: "#F8C5B3",
          400: "#F39A79",
          500: "#EE6F40",
          600: "#D6643A",
          700: "#8F4326",
          800: "#6B321D",
          900: "#472113",
        },
        rioGrande: {
          100: "#F7FAE7",
          200: "#EBF2C2",
          300: "#DFEA9D",
          400: "#C7DA54",
          500: "#AFCA0B",
          600: "#9EB60A",
          700: "#697907",
          800: "#4F5B05",
          900: "#353D03",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    backgroundColor: [
      "responsive",
      "hover",
      "focus",
      "group-hover",
      "focus-within",
    ],
    textColor: ["hover", "focus", "group-hover"],
    borderWidth: ["hover", "responsive"],
    borderColor: ["hover", "focus", "focus-within"],
    boxShadow: ["responsive", "hover", "focus", "focus-within"],
    scale: ["responsive", "hover", "focus", "group-hover"],
  },
  plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/custom-forms")],
};
```

And I want to have a new palette color called "primary" whitch contain the value of the palette "leaf","riotGrande" or "coral".

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work